# SQL Server 2016 integrated SP2 download & Install

Tags: sql-server, service-pack

I am installing SQL 2016 for a client across a number of VMs and looking to patch to SP2.
Can i download SQL Server 2016 integrated with SP2 so i can implement in the one go? Or does it need to be done separate?

Answer (score 0):

This article shows the process of how to slipstream a SQL Server installation along with later service packs and cumulative updates.  It's for SQL Server 2012 and 2014, but I would think that the process is the same for SQL Server 2016:

https://www.sqlshack.com/slipstreaming-sql-server-2012-2014/